# Proper way of implementing stream relay

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor

I'm implementing a stream relay using webflux. I have a `@GetControler("{id}")` which returns `Flux<byte[]>`, and a `@PostController("{id}")` which receives `Flux<byte[]>`.

What's the proper way of implementing?

I accomplished the task using `Sinks.One<Flux<byte[]>>`, but I think this is wired since it's wrapping "future" inside "future". I was thinking `Sinks.Many<byte[]>` but that won't work because there is no "pausing" back-pressure, and the buffer will eventually overflow.

BTW, what should I return for the "sender" side? `void`? `Disposable`? `Mono.never()`?

BTW 2, I tried `DataBuffer`, but it seems to have wired "double free" issue. Especially in scenario of multi-casing. What's the proper way of using this?

Comment: Is this about sending and receiving files via RESTful http requests? Or do you want to stream bytes in a Flux?

Comment: @Erunafailaro bytes